# Element on focus event listener is not being triggered using element.focus()

Tags: javascript, focus, addeventlistener, onfocus

Any idea why the event listener is not being triggered in this case?

If I change `focus` to `click`, it works fine.

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/cda3tpfq/

html:

```
<div id="result">
  No focus.
</div>
```

js:

```
var myElement = document.createElement('myElement');
myElement.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
myElement.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Focus recieved.';
});

myElement.focus();
```

Comment: Your created element is not part of the DOM, and it's not an interactive element.

Comment: @Pointy "it's not an interactive element.", can you elaborate?

Comment: changing `focus` to `click`, it works fine .. why?

Comment: your 'myElement' variable is never appended to the DOM

Comment: @bobbyrne01 "click" is a different event from "focus". Not every element can be focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to update the inner text in the div, something like this should work..

html:

```
<div id="result" tabindex="-1">no focus</div>
```

js:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('result');
myElement.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    myElement.innerText = 'Focus received.';
},true);
```

Then either manually click on the div to focus or use myElement.focus()

Comment: did you try your code? no functional difference to my code

Comment: sorry try now - it was missing the 'tabindex' attribute

Comment: you could create a new element and add the same functionality but just make sure you append it to the DOM. Are you trying to update the text in the current div or add a new div with different text in? Let me know either way and I will update my answer.